# Evaluate integral bound by 2 spheres

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\int_c (2-y^{3})dx + (x^{3}+ey^{2})dy$ where c is the boundary of the region between two spheres $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} = 9$ and $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} = 16$
So far I have noted there are two spheres one with a radius of $3$ and other with radius of $4$. And I am thinking you can use green theorem $p = (2-y^{3})$ and $q = (x^{3}+ey^{2})$ but I feel like that is incorrect.

Comment: what method would you recommend using for a problem like this?

Comment: I think that something is wrong because the boundary of the the area between the two spheres is a surface and the line integral over a surface doesn't make sense.  Maybe it's supposed to be a surface integral and you're supposed to use Stokes?

Comment: Is the region between the spheres solid? If so, try Gauss's Theorem (divergence theorem).